# command to accept VirtualBox PUEL (for virtualbox-ext-pack installation)?

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox, debconf

i'm creating a script for downloading and installing some programs and adjust their settings without the need for an interaction during the whole process.

so far so good, but now i'm stuck at the `virtualbox-ext-pack`: it stops the whole process and waits until the [*VirtualBox PUEL*](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox_PUEL) is accepted or rejected (similar to `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, `steam`, etc.).
for `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` there is a [solution found in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/25614/354350) with a one-liner, but since i'm not familiar with `debconf` (and investigating with `gkdebconf` also doesn't get me further) i have no clue what command(s) to use for installing `virtualbox-ext-pack` unattended.

Comment: also see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289685/how-to-install-virtualbox-extension-pack-to-virtualbox-latest-version-on-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks to [this solution for `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`](https://askubuntu.com/a/25614/354350) and the hints in [this question for `steam`](https://askubuntu.com/q/506909/354350) i figured out the correct command for `virtualbox-ext-pack`:

```
echo virtualbox-ext-pack virtualbox-ext-pack/license select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

Comment: This solution does not work with recent versions of VirtualBox

Comment: to install `virtualbox-ext-pack` from the repositories this solution still works! - and thus no special `VBoxManage`-commands and no need for manual preparation with an uuid, i prefer this solution. but for recent versions (from the vortualbox-repo) your answer is very useful, thanks @Jaime !

Answer (score 4):

As the UUID changes from version to version (or whenever the PUEL is updated), it can be accepted by ...

```
echo "y" | sudo VBoxManage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.2.0.vbox-extpack
```

Comment: A more general command for this purpose [is `yes`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) 

Answer (score 1):

In the command line, you can use the [`--accept-license` parameter](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16674) to perform an unattended installation.

```
sudo VBoxManage extpack install <package> --accept-license=<uuid>
```

---

**How to obtain the UUID for the `--accept-license` ?**

The `--accept-license` requires an UUID that you must obtain accepting the license manually.

1. You must run the installer manually first. For the 5.2.0 version,

   ```
   wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.0/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.2.0.vbox-extpack
   sudo VBoxManage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.2.0.vbox-extpack
   ```
2. The installer will show you a license text that you must accept

   ```
   VirtualBox Extension Pack Personal Use and Evaluation License (PUEL)

   License version 10, 20 July 2017

   PLEASE READ THE FOLLOWING ORACLE VM VIRTUALBOX EXTENSION PACK PERSONAL
     :

   Do you agree to these license terms and conditions (y/n)? y
   ```
3. After you accept, the installer will show you the UUID for the accept license.

   ```
   License accepted. For batch installaltion add
   --accept-license=b674970f720eb020ad18926a9268607089cc1703908696d24a04aa870f34c8e8
   to the VBoxManage command line.
   ```

---

**How to use the `--accept-license` ?**

Once you have the UUID, you can use the command line to perform an unattended installation. For the 5.2.0 version,

```
sudo VBoxManage extpack install $HOME/installers/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.2.0.vbox-extpack \
    --accept-license=b674970f720eb020ad18926a9268607089cc1703908696d24a04aa870f34c8e8
```

Answer (score 0):

To install a software that requires EULA acceptance, it can be automated as below. I did it for msodbcsql17, change your application.

```bash
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17 -y
```